# Отправка файла на веб сервис через java servlets

Tags: java, файлы, servlet

Есть веб форма, в которой есть возможность отправки файла на сервер на сервлетах java. Не могу сообразить, как мне организовать принятие файла и отправку его на сторонний веб сервис. При этом через минуту, нужно обратиться к веб сервису для проверки на успех/ошибку. Интересует именно то, как мне переслать файл на сервис. Нужно ли создавать файл-шаблон или сохранять файл в директории сервера или есть другие способы? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://github.com/javaee/tutorial-examples/blob/master/web/servlet/fileupload/src/main/java/javaeetutorial/fileupload/FileUploadServlet.java

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, спасибо, с тем как получить файл на сервере разобрался по этой ссылке. Остался вопрос с отправкой его на веб сервис.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading